# getText() which is in between <div> </div> tag?

Tags: automated-testing, javascript, protractor, jasmine, regex

1. Get text which are in between tags
   DOM

```html
<div id="div_ResultMessage" class="AlertmsgDiv">
    <div id="lblSuccessMessage" class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable">
        <div class="fa fa-check-square-o"></div>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            Pur. Requisition No. Acc000056Zip created successfully
            <spam class="DivPrint">
                <a onclick="window.open('/ZipERP/CommonLayout/PrintPurchaseRequisition?id=769e9c10-7a5f-4205-920e-6f967f18811e')" href="#" class="fa fa-print" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Print">  
                </a>
            </spam>
        </div>
     </div>
```

I want to get this text if you can see it in DOM `Pur. Requisition No. Acc000056Zip created successfully`

I have tried fetching the text and store it in a `var`

```js
var str = "";
 str = element(by.id('#lblSuccessMessage')).getAttribute('value');
```

and also this:

```js
var str = "";
str = element(by.id('#lblSuccessMessage')).getText().then(function(text){
console.log(text);
return text;
});
```

Actually I am making a purchase requistion and there is alert which generates the Purchase requistition no but it contains Pr. no but surrounded with texts for that I am applying `regEx` and it says `str.match()` is not a `function`.

For `regEx` I have tried this

```js
prno = str.match(/ Pur. Requisition No. Acc(\d+)/i)[0];
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more on your question? What are results of your trial? What is the concrete issue? To get a text or to parse it with regexp?

Comment: @AlexeyR. i have attached the DOM and mentioned what i want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I got solution for this:

```js
var str = $('#lblSuccessMessage').getText().then(function(text){
        console.log(text); 
        var r = /\d+/;
        console.log((text.match(r)[0]));
        prno = text.match(r)[0];
        //prno = str.match(/ Pur. Requisition No. Acc(\d+)/i)[0];
      });
      //console.log("Purchase requistion no..."+prno);
```